# Ionic & Firebase Google Login with Googleplus plugin error: 10

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic2, firebase-authentication, google-signin

So I'm trying to figure out the Google login system using Ionic, Googleplus plugin & Firebase.  I set everything up according to the following tutorial:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Then I ran the code on my phone as Ionic-run Android. When I do that I get an error 10. I looked it up and according to the following link:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243

It seems like it's an issue with the debug version and the key? In Firebase, I set up an Android project with the debug key but I didn't add the Google.services.json or add the code they told me to add in my build.gradle file because I get an error. I also activated the google sign in method.  Then I copied the demo app index.  I'm not sure If I missed a step or didn't set something up correctly.

Comment: EDIT:  Okay so I moved back to my Phonegap project and went through the same process and for some reason it worked, Although the profile image didn't display for some reason but the other account info showed up!  I don't know what I did differently.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's helpful for anyone else, I spent a lot of time troubleshooting this issue on Android. You need to make sure that your client_id for a credential of type "Web application" is used even though the SHA1 certificate hash you generate is associated with an OAuth2 credential of type Android.  I was using the Android client_id instead of the Web application one.  More info here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/425

Comment: Thank you very much, almost spent a week figuring out this.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by using a different project, not really sure what changed.